# Exceeding Maximum Number of my.settings

Tags: vb.net, application-settings

I am creating an application and once I exceeded 256 items in the application settings, visual studio will automatically create a second settings file `Settings1.Designer.vb`.

The result is that when I build the application I get

```
Error   5   'Settings' is ambiguous between declarations in Modules
```

I can delete the setting and the file and the program will run but I can no longer add additional settings. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have *that* many, the app might benefit from a Class to store them, this would allow any numerics or date Types to retain their Type and you can save the list to disk in 2-3 lines of code.  That many Settings also sounds like you are using more as a database (same solution).

Comment: I believe I have resolved my own question.  The issue of Visual Studio automatically creating addition settings files only occurs when exiting the GUI.  If I edit the 'Settings.Designer.vb directly', I can add properties as needed.  This seems to be the best solution since all of my properties have bindings.  Additionally this also is an issue regarding the Resource file, and editing that directly without opening the GUI _seems_ works for that as well.